# Tensorflow TFRecord: Can't parse serialized example

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tf-records) in order to serialize my input data into the TFRecord format but I keep hitting this error when trying to read it:

> InvalidArgumentError: Key: my_key.  Can't parse serialized Example.

I am not sure where I'm going wrong. Here is a minimal reproduction of the issue I cannot get past.

**Serialise some sample data:**

```
with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('train.tfrecords') as writer:
  for idx in range(10):
        example = tf.train.Example(
            features=tf.train.Features(
                feature={
                    'label': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[1,2,3])),
                    'test': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[0.1,0.2,0.3])) 
                }
            )
        )

        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
  writer.close()
```

**Parsing function & deserialise:**

```
def parse(tfrecord):
  features = {
      'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64, default_value=0),
      'test': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32, default_value=0.0),
  }
  return tf.parse_single_example(tfrecord, features)

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('train.tfrecords').map(parse)
getnext = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

When trying to run this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  v = sess.run(getnext)
  print (v)
```

I trigger the above error message.

Is it possible to get past this error and deserialize my data?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[tf.FixedLenFeature()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/FixedLenFeature) is used for reading the fixed size arrays of data. And the shape of the data should be defined beforehand. Updating the parse function to

```
def parse(tfrecord):
   return tf.parse_single_example(tfrecord, features={
       'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.int64, default_value=[0,0,0]),
       'test': tf.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.float32, default_value=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
   })
```

Should do the job.

Comment: Should the shape of the data include batch size or not?

Comment: @Rama, usually no. As a rule, the ds = ds.batch() is placed after the tfrecord parsing. Therefore, at this stage of data pipeline the records are not yet grouped into batches. So, no need to specify it's size here.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/RaggedFeature might be useful as well.

Answer (score 12):

As an alternative, if your input features lengths are not fixed and are of arbitrary sizes then you can also use `tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature()` with arguments `allow_missing = True` and `default_value=0` (in case of type int and 0.0 for float) which does not require the input feature to be of fixed size unlike `tf.io.FixedLenFeature()`. You can find more information [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/FixedLenSequenceFeature).