# InvalidArgumentError: Key: label. Can't parse serialized Example: How can I find a way to parse the one-hot encoded labels from TFRecords?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, tfrecord

I got 12 folders (which are categories of my data) containing images. This code converts images and their corresponding labels into tfrecord data with compressing it efficiently:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from pathlib import Path
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm
from os import listdir
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from tqdm import tqdm

labels = {v:k for k, v in enumerate(listdir('train/'))}
labels

class GenerateTFRecord:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = Path(path)
        self.labels = {v:k for k, v in enumerate(listdir(path))}

    def convert_image_folder(self, tfrecord_file_name):
        # Get all file names of images present in folder
        img_paths = list(self.path.rglob('*.jpg'))

        with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_file_name) as writer:
            for img_path in tqdm(img_paths, desc='images converted'):
                example = self._convert_image(img_path)
                writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

    def _convert_image(self, img_path):
        label = self.labels[img_path.parent.stem]
        img_shape = mpimg.imread(img_path).shape

        # Read image data in terms of bytes
        with tf.io.gfile.GFile(img_path, 'rb') as fid:
            image_data = fid.read()

        example = tf.train.Example(features = tf.train.Features(feature = {
            'rows': tf.train.Feature(int64_list = tf.train.Int64List(value = [img_shape[0]])),
            'cols': tf.train.Feature(int64_list = tf.train.Int64List(value = [img_shape[1]])),
            'channels': tf.train.Feature(int64_list = tf.train.Int64List(value = [3])),
            'image': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list = tf.train.BytesList(value = [image_data])),
            'label': tf.train.Feature(int64_list = tf.train.Int64List(value = tf.one_hot(label, depth=len(labels), on_value=1, off_value=0))),
        }))
        return example

t = GenerateTFRecord(path='train/')
t.convert_image_folder('data.tfrecord')
```

Then I use this code here to read the tfrecord data and create my `tf.data.Dataset`:

```
def _parse_function(tfrecord):
    # Extract features using the keys set during creation
    features = {
        'rows': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'cols': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'channels': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
    }

    # Extract the data record
    sample = tf.io.parse_single_example(tfrecord, features)

    image = tf.image.decode_image(sample['image'])
    label = sample['label']
    # label = tf.one_hot(label, depth=len(labels), on_value=1, off_value=0)
    return image, label

def configure_for_performance(ds, buffer_size, batch_size):
    ds = ds.cache()
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=buffer_size)
    return ds


def generator(tfrecord_file, batch_size, n_data, validation_ratio, reshuffle_each_iteration=False):
    reader = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=[tfrecord_file])
    reader.shuffle(n_data, reshuffle_each_iteration=reshuffle_each_iteration)
    AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

    val_size = int(n_data * validation_ratio)
    train_ds = reader.skip(val_size)
    val_ds = reader.take(val_size)

    train_ds = train_ds.map(_parse_function, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    train_ds = configure_for_performance(train_ds, AUTOTUNE, batch_size)

    val_ds = val_ds.map(_parse_function, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    val_ds = configure_for_performance(val_ds, AUTOTUNE, batch_size)
    return train_ds, val_ds
```

And in here I create my model:

```
from os.path import isdir, dirname, abspath, join
from os import makedirs

from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.applications import DenseNet121
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam


def create_model(optimizer, freeze_layer=False):
  densenet = DenseNet121(weights='imagenet', 
                        include_top=False)

  if freeze_layer:
    for layer in densenet_model.layers:
      if 'conv5' in layer.name:
        layer.trainable = True
      else:
        layer.trainable = False

  model = Sequential()
  model.add(densenet)
  model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
  model.add(Dense(12, activation='softmax'))

  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.99, epsilon=1e-6)
    densenet_model = create_model(optimizer)

    tfrecord_file = 'data.tfrecord'
    n_data = len(list(Path('train').rglob('*.jpg')))
    train, val = generator(tfrecord_file, 2, n_data, validation_ratio, True)

    validation_ratio = 0.2
    val_size = int(n_data * validation_ratio)
    train_size = n_data - val_size
    batch_size = 32
    n_epochs = 300
    n_workers = 5

    filename = '/content/drive/MyDrive/data.tfrecord'


    train_ds, val_ds = generator(filename,
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            n_data=n_data,
                            validation_ratio=validation_ratio,
                            reshuffle_each_iteration=True)


   hist = densenet_model.fit(train_ds,
                      validation_data=val_ds,
                      epochs=n_epochs,
                      workers=n_workers,
                      steps_per_epoch=train_size//batch_size,
                      validation_steps=val_size)
```

This is the error I get each time:

`InvalidArgumentError:  Key: label.  Can't parse serialized Example. [[{{node ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExampleV2}}]] [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_343514]`

Obviously there is something wrong with the `label` in my tfrecord data.

I really need to know that based on my model output shape (12,) how can I safely have one hot encoded label store in my tfrecord and parse in `tf.data.Dataset`?

Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504855/7610724) the arrays of data should be fixed size, So I think it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize with Feature Size might be solve in case.

```
'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([SIZE_OF_FEATURE], tf.int64, default_value=[0,0,0])
```

Best of Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the label when reading the tfrecord file, inside your `_parse_function` function:

```
label = tf.cast(sample['label'], dtype=tf.int32)
```

I hope this will solve the InvalidArgumentError message.