# TFRecords InvalidArgumentError: Key: x_img_shape. Can't parse serialized Example

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'd like to make TFRecords into TFRecordsDataset. And unpack the data while feeding it. This is my function for parsing.

```py
def read_tfrecord(tfrecord, epochs, batch_size):

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecord)

    def parse(record):
        features = {
        "x_img": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "x_img_shape": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64), 
        "x_spectrogram": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "x_spec_shape": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64), 
        "x_wave": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "x_wave_shape": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64), 
        "y":tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "y_shape": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}

        example = tf.io.parse_single_example(record, features)
        x_image = tf.io.decode_image(example["x_img"])
        x_spec = tf.io.decode_image(example["x_spectrogram"])
        x_wave = tf.cast(example["x_wave"], tf.string)
        y = tf.io.decode_image(example["y"])
        return x_image, x_spec, x_wave, y

    dataset = dataset.map(parse)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=5)        
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=batch_size)  #
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(epochs)

    return dataset
```

I made an iterator to do the task:

```
train_files = path + "train.tfrecords"
EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 5

train_dataset = read_tfrecord(tfrecord=train_files,
                              epochs=EPOCHS,
                              batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
iterator = iter(train_dataset)
x_img, x_spec, x_wave, y = next(iterator)
```

But I got this error:

> InvalidArgumentError: Key: x_img_shape.  Can't parse serialized Example.
> [[{{node ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExampleV2}}]]

The code that serializes the data:

```
with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(tfrcpath) as file_writer:
    for video in sorted(video_list):
        print(video)

        x_img = frame_extraction(raw_loc, video, interval)
        x_spec, x_wave = audio_extraction(raw_loc, video, interval)
        y = ground_truth_extraction(raw_loc, video, ground_truth, interval) 

        record_bytes = tf.train.Example(
            features= tf.train.Features(
                feature={
                    "x_img": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value= x_img.flatten())),
                    "x_img_shape": tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value= x_img.shape)), 
                    "x_spec": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value= x_spec.flatten())),
                    "x_spec_shape": tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value= x_spec.shape)), 
                    "x_wave": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value= x_wave.flatten())),
                    "x_wave_shape": tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value= x_wave.shape)), 
                    "y": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value= y.flatten())),
                    "y_shape": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value= y.shape)),

                    })).SerializeToString()

        file_writer.write(record_bytes)
```

### What I have tried:

Solution in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53499409/tensorflow-tfrecord-cant-parse-serialized-example) suggests adding the shape of the data. So I tried update it as `"x_img_shape": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.int64)`, but didn't solve my issue.

### My questions are:

1. What is the error meaning?
2. Why is the error only shows at `x_img_shape` but not `x_img`? `x_img_shape` is only used to record the shape of the images
3. Since I did flatten the images when writing theam as TFRecords, do I need to reshape the training images back? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: If you could post the code that serialized the data, that would be helpful. Also check that `"x_img_shape"` was serialized as a `tf.train.Int64List`. It could have been serialized as a `tf.train.BytesList`, so parsing it as an `tf.int64` instead of a `tf.string` would be problematic.

Comment: @gobrewers14 yes, I will update it in the original post

Comment: @gobrewers14 I think my problem just matches what you mentioned. And to be honest, I'm not really sure what I'm doing regarding the datatypes. I expect that since I serialized as a `tf.train.Int64List`, I should have able to parse it as a `tf.int64`, but that's not the case. Could you explain that a bit?

Comment: I just update the code and make `tf.int64` as `tf.string`. But it returns `InvalidArgumentError: Key: x_img_shape. Data types don't match. Data type: int64 but expected type: string`